# Examples of extremally disconnected spaces

Tags: general-topology, operator-theory, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

I am trying to understand the notion of extremally disconnected space
(in other words Stonean space),
i.e. a space in which any open set has an open closure.
Could you help me and give (reasonable) examples of such spaces except discrete space?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremally_disconnected_space

Comment: Why was this tagged ([tag:operator-theory])?

Comment: @MartinSleziak, see my post below

Comment: Spacebook might be worth checking when searching for examples: http://topology.jdabbs.com/properties/49?traits=deduced

Comment: Stonean requires compact in addition to extremally disconnected see https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1967-018-02/S0002-9939-1967-0210066-0/S0002-9939-1967-0210066-0.pdf Extremally Disconnected Spaces
Dona Papert Strauss, Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, Vol. 18, No. 2 (Apr., 1967), pp. 305-309. Also at https://www.jstor.org/stable/2035286

Answer (score 9):

*Maybe its to late for You but this might be helpful for someone else*

A topological space $K$ is said to be extremally disconnected if $ \bar U$ is open for every open $U ⊆ K$; equivalently, in $K$ the following separation axiom is satisfied:

If $U, V ⊆ K$ are open and $U ∩ V = \emptyset $ then $\bar U ∩ \bar V = ∅$.

This separation is extremally (sic!) storng, and unusual, I can't think of any natural examples that do not come from Stone spaces of boolean algebras.

By an ultrafilter $ \mathcal F$ in boolean algebra $ \mathfrak A = (A,0,1, -, \vee, \wedge)$ we call a subset of $A$ such that:

- $1 \in \mathcal F $ and $ 0 \not \in \mathcal F$
- $a, b \in \mathcal F $ then $a \wedge b \in \mathcal F$
- $a \in \mathcal F$, $b \geq a$ then $ b \in \mathcal F$
- for every $a \in A$ either $a \in \mathcal F$ or $ -a \in \mathcal F$

Assuming AC every boolean algebra has an ultrafilter. A Stone space $K$ of boolean algebra $\mathfrak A$ is a set of all ultrafilters of $\mathfrak A$ called $\mathrm{Ult } \ \mathfrak A $ with topology generated by base set of a form $ \hat a$, $ a \in A$ where:
$$ \hat a = \{ \mathcal F \in \mathrm{Ult} \ \mathfrak A : \ a \in \mathcal F \}$$

**Theorem** The space $K$ is a compact, totally disconnected topological space. Observe that it from this disconnectedness and compactness with have zero-dimensionality.

The mapping $a \mapsto \hat a$ is boolean isomorphism between $ \mathfrak A$ and algebra of a clopen sets in $K$.

**Theorem** The algebra $\mathfrak A$ is complete (every subfamily has a least upperbound) iff $K$ is extremally disconnected.

**Example** Consider algebra $ \mathfrak A = \mathcal P (\mathbb N )$ with natural operations. It is complete, a subset $\mathcal S$ has an upper bound $ \bigcup \mathcal S$. Hence $K_{\mathfrak A} = \beta \mathbb N$ ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification#The_Stone.E2.80.93.C4.8Cech_compactification_of_the_natural_numbers)) is extremally disconnected.

**Example** Let $\mathfrak B$ be the the measure algebra, i.e. the family of all equivalence classes $[B], B ∈ Bor[0, 1]$ where:
$$[B] = \{ A ∈ Bor[0, 1] : λ(A \Delta B) = 0\}$$
This is again complete, by taking the sum and assuring that it is countable one by some approximation theorems. So its Stone space $K_{\mathfrak B}$ is extremally disconnected.

**Remark** One can check that $\ell^\infty$ is isometric to $C ( \beta \mathbb N)$ and $L^\infty [0, 1]$ is isometric to $C(K_{\mathfrak B})$.

Someone objected what this topic has to do with operator theory. But the notion of extremal disconnectedness arises naturally in functional analysis:

**Theorem** Space K is an extremally disconnected compact space iff $C(K)$
is an order complete Banach lattice, i.e. for every bounded from above family $Φ ⊆ C(K)$ there is an least upper bound in $C(K)$.

A Banach space $X$ is 1-injective if for every Banach space $F$ and its subspace $E$ every bounded operator $T : E → X$ has an extension to a bounded operator $ \bar T : F → X$ such that $ \| \bar T \| = \| T \|$.

**Example** Space $\mathbb R$ is 1-injective, which is exactly Hahn-Banach theorem.

**Example** Space $\ell^\infty$ is 1-injective by using Hahn-Banach for every coordinate.

**Theorem [Kelly]** A Banach space $X$ is 1-injective iff it is isometric to $C(K)$ space with $K$ extremally disconnected.

**Corollary** Space $L^\infty [0,1]$ is 1-injective.

Notion of 1-injectivity is important in isomorphic theory of seperable Banach spaces, and extremal disconectedness gives us some characterisation of this property.

---

Reference: [Lecture notes on combinatorics in Banach spaces](http://www.math.uni.wroc.pl/~grzes/dydaktyka13_14/lectures_in_Katowice.pdf)

Comment: Usage of [sic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic) in "extremally (sic!) storng" suggests that you are quoting from somewhere, but it is unclear which part of your post is a quote or where the quote is taken from.

Comment: Good eye. ;-) This answer is partially taken from my lecture notes on a course 'combinatorics in Banach spaces' given by professor Grzegorz Plebanek.

Comment: The natural next question is whether the notes are available online = since that might be useful addition to post. But I guess that if they are available somewhere, it will probably be [only in Polish](https://www.google.com/search?q=Kombinatoryka%20+przestrzeniach+Banacha+plebanek).

Comment: Actually they are available in English :) Not exactly from my course, but this topic is also covered. Some theorems are taken exactly from there. I edited my answer. Sorry for not giving references at first. I am still not used to answering rather than asking questions. :p

Comment: Thanks for adding the link. I think that it improves the answer in several ways: 1) If part of your answer is quote from somewhere, it is a good practice to include reference. 2) If somebody wants to see proofs and further references for theorems you listed, they can find them in the notes. 3) There is a lot of other interesting material there, so this link might be interesting not only in connection with the original question.

Answer (score 3):

Two simple examples of [extremally disconnected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremally_disconnected_space) spaces are $\mathbb{N}$ (or any infinite set) with the [cofinite topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Cofinite_topology) $\mathcal{T}=\{A:|\mathbb{N}\setminus A|<\aleph_0\}\cup\{\varnothing\}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ with the [right order topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology#Left_and_right_order_topologies) $\mathcal{T}=\{(a,\infty):a\in\mathbb{R}\}\cup\{\varnothing,\mathbb{R}\}$.  In each, the closure of any nonempty open set is the whole space, hence open, and of course, every topological space satisfies $\overline\varnothing=\varnothing$, which is also open.

**Note.** Some texts such as Steen and Seebach's [*Counterexamples in Topology*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterexamples_in_Topology) (SS) restrict the definition of extremal disconnectedness to Hausdorff spaces, which the above two are not. They are [*hyperconnected*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperconnected_space) spaces, all of which are extremally disconnected (without the Hausdorff restriction).

The Hausdorff restriction limits the number of extremally disconnected spaces in SS to just these five:

- [Discrete Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space)
- [Stone–Čech Compactification of the Integers](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000108)
- [Strong Ultrafilter Topology](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000110)
- [Single Ultrafilter Topology](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000111)
- [Sierpiński's Metric Space](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000002)

Comment: Do Extremally Disconnected spaces have non trivial dense subsets? What would be an example, say, of a dense subset of the measure algebra $\{[B] : B \in Bor[0,1]\}$? Is this space Extremally Disconnected but not Totally Disconnected?